# why $\int{\cos({\pi}t)} dt = \frac{1}{\pi}\sin({\pi}t)$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Why?

$$\int{\cos({\pi}t)} dt = \frac{1}{\pi}\sin({\pi}t)$$

the indefinite integral of $ \cos(x) = \sin(x) $ isn't it?

so this suppose to be $$\int{\cos({\pi}t)} dt = \sin({\pi}t)$$

Why in the video at the minute 3:50 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuWaisQj3hU&index=29&list=PLF5E22224459D23D9) the professor says the first one?

Am I missing something?

please explain to me step by step and in detail. Thank you very much.

Comment: Try a change of variables. Set $u = \pi t \implies du = \pi dt \implies \frac{du}{\pi} = dt$ and integrate over $u$. Alternatively, use the chain rule to differentiate $$\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi}$$ and see what you get.

Comment: It would be what you're saying if differentiation was done with respect to piT, but it isn't. It's an application of the chain rule. Differentiating sin(piT) gives picos(piT) ... But we only want sin(piT) so we divide by pi,

Comment: When something new is "added" we can assume the old rules will work, but often they don't work meaning there's more going on than we know. One way to think is to always remember that the rules we know at present are some special case of more general rules. So e.g. your statement $\int\cos(x)dx=\sin(x)+C$ is a special way of writing $\int\cos(1\cdot x)=\sin(x)+C$, but what if the $1$ were some other number $a$. What general rule is there to handle such cases? It's not as straight forward as the case when $a=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $u$-substitution, let $u = \pi t$, then
$$\int \cos(\pi t)\,dt = \int \cos(u)\cdot\frac{1}{\pi}\,du = \frac{1}{\pi}\sin(\pi t)+C$$

To check your work, you can take the derivative of the RHS to check that it matches the integrand:
$$\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\sin(\pi t)+C\right)' = \frac{1}{\pi}\cos (\pi t)\cdot \pi+0 = \cos(\pi t),$$
which matches the original integrand.

In fact, he explicitly says to take the derivative of "something" and that should match the integrand. That "something" is
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\sin(\pi t)+C.$$
Remember that the derivative of a constant is zero.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative $f'(x)$ is the slope of the tangent at point $x$ to the curve $y=f(x)$. If you change $x$ into $\pi x$, you are *shrinking* the curve : for instance $\sin(\pi x)$ oscillates $\pi$ times faster that $\sin(x)$. This is why the factor $\pi$ is necessary : the slope of the tangent is $\pi$ times larger.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking why:

Due to chain rule, when we differentiate $\sin\pi t$ wrt $t$, we get an additional constant $\pi$ which is the coefficient of $t$

$$\dfrac{d(\sin\pi t)}{dt} = \cos\pi t \cdot \pi$$

So when we differentiate $\dfrac{\sin\pi t}{\pi}$ wrt $t$, we get $\cos\pi$

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\sin\pi t}{\pi}\right) = \cos\pi t $$

hence $$\int \cos(\pi t) \ dt = \frac{\sin\pi t}{\pi} + C$$

Answer (score 0):

$\int \cos \left(\pi x\right)dx$

> $\mathrm{Apply\:Integral\:Substitution:}\:\int
> > f\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\cdot g^{'}\left(x\right)dx=\int
> > f\left(u\right)du,\:\quad u=g\left(x\right)$ $u=\pi x\quad \:du=\pi
> > dx$
>
> $\mathrm{Substitute:}\:u=\pi x$
>
> $\frac{du}{dx}=\pi $
>
> $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\pi x\right)$
>
> $\mathrm{Take\:the\:constant\:out}:\quad \left(a\cdot
> > f\right)^{'}=a\cdot f^{'}$
>
> $=\pi \frac{d}{dx}\left(x\right)$
>
> $\mathrm{Apply\:the\:common\:derivative}:\quad
> > \frac{d}{dx}\left(x\right)=1$
>
> $=\pi 1$
>
> $\mathrm{Simplify}$
>
> $=\pi $
>
> $\Rightarrow \:du=\pi dx$
>
> $\Rightarrow \:dx=\frac{1}{\pi }du$
>
> $=\int \cos \left(u\right)\frac{1}{\pi }du$
>
> $=\int \frac{\cos \left(u\right)}{\pi }du$
>
> $=\int \frac{\cos \left(u\right)}{\pi }du$

$=\int \frac{\cos \left(u\right)}{\pi }du$

> $\mathrm{Take\:the\:constant\:out}:\quad \int a\cdot
> > f\left(x\right)dx=a\cdot \int f\left(x\right)dx$

$=\frac{1}{\pi }\int \cos \left(u\right)du$

> $\mathrm{Use\:the\:common\:integral}:\quad \int \:\cos
> > \left(u\right)du=\sin \left(u\right)$

$=\frac{1}{\pi }\sin \left(u\right)$

> $\mathrm{Substitute\:back}\:u=\pi x$

$=\frac{1}{\pi }\sin \left(\pi x\right)$

> $\mathrm{Simplify}$

$=\frac{\sin \left(\pi x\right)}{\pi }$

> $Add\:a\:constant\:to\:the\:solution$

$=\frac{\sin \left(\pi x\right)}{\pi }+C$